# Stochastic Differential Equation Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

So I'm again working on doing something similar to this paper and could use some help. In the paper they worked with the equation $N(t)[(a(t)-b(t)N(t))dt + \alpha(t)dB(t)]$. It's a normal logistic equation but here the usual parameters a,b are continuous T-periodic functions (whereas usually they're considered constants). Here is the excerpt from the paper:

[image: Excerpt from paper]

Now I want to do something similar, but to work with a modified equation: $N(t)[(a(t)-b(t)N(t))dt + \alpha(t)N(t)dB(t)]$. The difference is that in the original paper, the a(t) was stochastically perturbed, and not I'm perturbing the b(t). I would like to derive an $x(t)$ like they have.

I worked on it a bit and was able to derive the following:

$dx(t) = \left[ \frac{\alpha(t)^2}{x(t)} -a(t)x(t) + b(t)\right]dt - \alpha(t)dB(t)$.

What I'm stuck on being able to do is derive the $x(t)$ from this like they have. In this paper, they just gave an $x(t)$ and said it satisfies $dx(t)$. I can see the motivation of $x(t)$ if you're a bit informal and solve $dx(t)$ like it's a usual first-order differential equation. In the case I'm working on, I'm not so lucky. Can anyone please help me derive an $x(t)$ if it can be done? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served by going the other way and not having to guess. Thus set, like in quadratic Bernoulli equations, $x=1/N$, then as in the citation,
$$
dx=\frac1{N+dN}-\frac1N=-\frac{dN}{N^2}+\frac{dN^2}{N^3}+h.o.t
$$
where $dN^2=d⟨N⟩=d⟨N,N⟩$ and the higher order terms do not contribute in the integration of the SDE. With
$$
dN^2=(αN^2dB+h.o.t)^2=α^2N^4\,dt+h.o.t.
$$
one gets thus
$$
dx=-[(a·x−b)·dt+α·dB] + α^2/x·dt
$$
which does not seem as helpful as the same transformation in the original problem.

Comment: I agree it would be better not to have to guess, but the important part in the paper is the x(t) which is what I need to get. They're showing that from the x(t), you can get the N(t) which makes sense. I know what the N(t) should be, but I would like the x(t) (and thus can get N(t) by taking 1/x(t)), or if there's a way to get the N(t) directly from dN(t), that would work too.

Comment: Yes, I see I recomputed your result. I'm afraid there will be no closed formula, as often with non-linear differential equations. It is only the special cases where a fortunate, all-revealing transformation exists.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had a feeling there wouldn't be a closed formula. Perhaps it's possible to get one by defining N(t) to be something else other than 1/x(t), and then working backwards, dx(t) becomes something manageable to solve